# How to show all fields from a mysql table with PHP and str_replace

Tags: php, mysql, str-replace

I'm setting up a system for sending messages to whatsapp with PHP + MYSQL and a connection API.

I created a **submission form** where I defined some templates such as **{{name}}**, **{{expiration}}**, **{{codeticket}}** and I intend to send these templates embedded in my messages to all users who are registered in the MYSQL users table.

The goal is as follows:
When sending the message to all users, each user would receive the following msg:
Ex: *

> Hello {{name}} how are you? Below is your bank slip code:
> {{codeticket}} remembering that you need to pay by the day
> {{expiration}} Sincerely, Digital Support.
> *

For this to be possible I created a script that queries all fields in the users table where the "active" field is equal to "0" and the ID is equal to "3".

With that I created a "while" loop in PHP to get all the fields from the users table and then put the variables of each field in the url to send to whatsapp.

An example of code working without templates would look like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_ma ='". $id_ma ."' AND ativo = '".$ativo."'";
$qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$cont = mysqli_num_rows($qr);

if ($cont > 0) {
    //I make a loop with while to go through the bank and set each defaulting user.

    while ($txt = mysqli_fetch_array($qr, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $tags = array();
        $tags['name'] = $txt['nome'];
        $tags['expiration'] = $txt['data_expira'];
        $tags['linkgrupo'] = $txt['link_canal'];
        $tags['product'] = $txt['nome_prod'];
        $tags['codebillet'] = $txt['codigo_boleto'];
        $tags['link_billet'] = $txt['link_boleto'];
        foreach ($tags as $key => $valor) {
            $conteudo_msg = str_replace('{{'.$key.'}}', $valor, $conteudo_msg);
        }

        //Here I take the query data and send the msg to users via APi Whatsapp
        $url = "https://send.zaprapido.com.br/api/send.php?token=".$apiwhatsapp."&no=55".$txt["celular"]."&text=".urlencode(utf8_decode($txt['nome']))."+";
        //echo $url."<br />";
        //Vamos chamar a msg via Json pela APi

        $result = file_get_contents($url, true);
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
```

The problem is that when adding the variable **$content_msg** to work with the templates, the script is only taking the first line of each field and sending it to all the numbers registered in the database.

Comment: When you were including the `$content_msg` variable in the url, were you escaping it?

Comment: Could you show in your example where you would add `$content_msg`?

Comment: Why do you use `utf8_decode`? Do you know the purpose of this function?

Comment: Hello I'm using utf8_decode because of an encoding problem with my database. When I type anything in the form it registers with strange characters, the utf8_decode is precisely to prevent these characters from being sent to the final user.

Answer (score 0):

Each while loop you need to set `$conteudo_msg` to the template, otherwise, it will have the value of previous and there will not be a `{{key}}` to be replaced.

```
...
$conteudo_msg = $template;
foreach($tags as $key => $valor)
{
    $conteudo_msg = str_replace('{{'.$key.'}}', $valor, $conteudo_msg);
}       
...
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but there is a typo in your code. In your `$conteudo_msg` you have `{{codeticket}}`, but in your `$tags` array, you have `codebillet`.

Anyway, I would suggest you pass in only the variables you need to replace, because you're looping 3 extra times without actually replacing anything.

Comment: I was wrong with the question in $tags['codeticket'] I added the loop variable $txt['codeticket'] but when calling it inside str_replace it only returns the first row of the table, when I send the other numbers the first row if repeats inside the loop, it looks like PHP can't show the rows corresponding to each number listed in the users table. thanks.

Comment: @dosiro you are not allowed to hope that something helps :))

Comment: Guys I did all the tests here.
As much as I use str_replace PHP will never show
all data in the table.

It will always send only the first row of the table to all users.

In short, I know there is a solution, but str_replace is not viable.